# fetching just a byte range for an object (byte-offset + len) rather than full file

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am storing large files using Google Cloud Storage.  Sometimes I want to retrieve the full file, but often I want to retrieve just a specific range of bytes from the file.

If I know the byte offset and length that I need to retrieve, is there any way to just retrieve those bytes rather than the full file?  My motivation is to reduce time and bandwidth required to load the data.

This is a feature that is offered by Amazon's S3 and that I have been using for a while.  I am hoping that the same feature is offered by Google so that I can migrate from S3 to Google Cloud Storage.

Regards,

Oscar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a Range header in the GET request, such as:

```
range: bytes=123-456
```

This works for both the XML API (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api-overview) and the JSON API (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/).

Comment: Is there an option to do in with gsutil? Or some other API thats not rest?